# Angular argument assigning issue

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am trying an app in MEAN stack. I have created a contact list for add. edit, update,delete operation using MEAN. When I am trying to get all contacts from my Contact model I am getting the below errors in my code.

Kindly my code below.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {ContactService} from '../contact.service';
import {Contact} from '../contact';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-contacts',
  templateUrl: './contacts.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contacts.component.css'],
  providers: [ContactService]
})
export class ContactsComponent implements OnInit {
  contacts: Contact[];
  contact:Contact;
  first_name:string;
  last_name:string;
  phone:string;

  constructor(private contactService: ContactService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
        this.contactService.getContacts()
      .subscribe( contacts->this.contacts = contacts);
  }

}
```

I got the below errors when I run my application

```
ERROR in /var/www/html/contactlist/client/src/app/contacts/contacts.component.ts (22,28): Expression expected.

ERROR in /var/www/html/contactlist/client/src/app/contacts/contacts.component.ts (22,43): ',' expected.

ERROR in /var/www/html/contactlist/client/src/app/contacts/contacts.component.ts (22,19): Cannot find name 'contacts'. Did you mean the instance member 'this.contacts'?

ERROR in /var/www/html/contactlist/client/src/app/contacts/contacts.component.ts (22,19): Argument of type 'boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: any) => void'.

ERROR in /var/www/html/contactlist/client/src/app/contacts/contacts.component.ts (22,19): Operator '>' cannot be applied to types 'number' and 'Contact[]'.

ERROR in /var/www/html/contactlist/client/src/app/contacts/contacts.component.ts (22,45): Cannot find name 'contacts'. Did you mean the instance member 'this.contacts'?

ERROR in ./src/app/contacts/contacts.component.ts
Module parse failed: /var/www/html/contactlist/client/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/index.js!/var/www/html/contactlist/client/src/app/contacts/contacts.component.ts Unexpected token (18:35)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|     ContactsComponent.prototype.ngOnInit = function () {
|         this.contactService.getContacts()
|             .subscribe(contacts -  > this.contacts, contacts);
|     };
|     return ContactsComponent;
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts 12:0-66
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/main.ts
```

Comment: Change the name contacts to some other name inside subscribe function and try..

Comment: If I change the subscribe function as  `this.contactService.getContacts()
      .subscribe( contacts->this.contacts = getcontacts);
  } `                                                                                                                           I am getting cannot find name 'getcontacts' error.

Comment: Try this, I am not sure.  **.subscribe( myContacts->this.contacts = myContacts);**

Comment: Its not working. Still I am getting the same error

Comment: I fixed the issue the code should be `this.contactService.getContacts() .subscribe( contacts=>this.contacts = getcontacts); }`

Comment: Cool. But, what is getcontacts?

Comment: Sorry. I fixed the issue the code should be `this.contactService.getContacts() .subscribe( contacts=>this.contacts = contacts); }`